# How to update a set of markers in Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to update the set of markers I show in the map from client's form output.

The point where I'm stuck is in the ShowUser() function, the last statement is setMarkers(map, stations), I would expect the markers to be changed but it doesn't seems to work. Any help?

```
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.7291, 0.3379)
    }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);
  setMarkers(map, stations);
}

  var stations = [
  ['Rafa',40.0,-6.0,0],
  ['Josh',38.5,-1.0,1]
  ];

   function setMarkers(map, locations) {
      var image = ['circle_orange.png','circle_blue .png'];
      for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        var stations = locations[i];
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(stations[1], stations[2]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLng,
          map: map,
          icon: image[stations[3]],
          title: stations[0],
          zIndex: stations[3],
          optimized: false
        });
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: "No data available"
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
        infowindow.setContent("We can include any station information, for example: Lat/Long: "+ stations[1]+" , "+stations[2]);
        infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
      }
    }

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
function showUser(str) {
if (str != ""){
var stations = [
  ['Rafa',50.0,-6.0,0],
  ['Josh',58.5,-1.0,1]
  ];
 document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=stations;
 setMarkers(map, stations);
}
}
```

Comment: Maybe you need to manually call a redraw like so: google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');

Comment: remove this line `icon: image[stations[3]],` , when the markers appear the pathes for the icons are not correct. However, your code doesn't change markers, it will create new markers.

Comment: Thanks Dr.Molle, I don't see any problems with such line. Actually markers are perfectly loaded  before ShowUser() is executed.

Comment: map is a local variable, remove the `var`-keyword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dr. Molle points, the problem is with the map variable. It is initialized inside the initialize() function, which means it is not a global variable. Chrome Debugger tool is the way I used to find the problem. Following it is a link to a working example for reference:

[Example](http://www.sanwebe.com/2011/11/adding-markers-onclick-in-google-map)